# Как сделать лайки на Flask?

Tags: python, flask

У меня есть новостной сайт на flask, и я хочу сделать систему лайков в нём, но не знаю как.

Вот мой код:

```
@bp.route('/article/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def article(id):
    comment_form = CommentsCreateForm()
    like_form = LikesAndDislikes()
    article = db.session.query(Articles).filter(Articles.id == id).first()
    creator = db.session.query(User).filter(User.id == article.creator).first()
    comments = db.session.query(Comment).filter(Comment.article_id == id).all()  # список кометариев
    if comment_form.validate_on_submit():
        comment = Comment()
        comment.comment_creator = current_user.id
        comment.article_id = id
        comment.content = comment_form.text.data

        current_user.comment.append(comment)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template("news_template.html", article=article, creator=creator, comments=comments,
                               form=comment_form)
    return render_template("news_template.html", article=article, creator=creator, comments=comments, form=comment_form)
```

Форма для создания комментария

```
class CommentsCreateForm(FlaskForm):
    text = StringField('Введите коментарий', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Отправить')
```

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="card text-center">
    <img src="/static/img/{{article.image}}">
    <div class="card-body text-left">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ article.title }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{article.content}}</p>
        <p>Автор: {{creator.username}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-left">
        <button >
            <svg class="bi bi-caret-up" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="Green"
                 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                      d="M3.204 11L8 5.519 12.796 11H3.204zm-.753-.659l4.796-5.48a1 1 0 011.506 0l4.796 5.48c.566.647.106 1.659-.753 1.659H3.204a1 1 0 01-.753-1.659z"
                      clip-rule="evenodd"/>
            </svg>
        </button>
        {{article.likes}}
        <svg class="bi bi-caret-down" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="Red"
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                  d="M3.204 5L8 10.481 12.796 5H3.204zm-.753.659l4.796 5.48a1 1 0 001.506 0l4.796-5.48c.566-.647.106-1.659-.753-1.659H3.204a1 1 0 00-.753 1.659z"
                  clip-rule="evenodd"/>
        </svg>
        {{article.dislikes}}
    </div>
</div>

{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <div class="form-group row">
        {{ form.text.label(class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label") }}
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            {{ form.text(type="email", class="form-control", id="colFormLabel", placeholder="col-form-label") }}
        </div>
        {% for error in form.text.errors %}
        <p class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {{ error }}
        </p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <p>{{ form.submit(type="submit", class="btn btn-primary") }}</p>
</form>
{% endif %}


<h3>Коментарии</h3>
<div class="list-group">
    {% for comment in comments %}

    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h5 class="mb-1">{{ comment.comment_creator }}</h5>
            <small>{{comment.created_date}}</small>
        </div>
        <p class="mb-1">{{comment.content}}</p>
    </a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Что именно вы попробовали? Что не получилось?

Comment: @insolor я пытался использовать чек боксы из wtf-forms, но не понял как отправить ответ на сервер без кнопки submit